# Cat scared of me after bag incident

Tags: cats

My nan came around with a bag of goodies, my cat (Penny) was sniffing the bag and got her head stuck. Plastic shopping bag that was empty.

She ran around the flat 3 times before landing in the bath, we got the bag of her, she got herself wet and scratched me... now she's never been that keen on me, she loves my other half! But since then, 6 or so hours later, she's taken treats of me, eaten and drunk but then hisses at me, gets her fur and back up and it's heartbreaking!

She sat with my other half for a while but hasn't settled since and I'm so worried about my relationship with her and her calming down :(

Comment: Do you think that this answer (mine, from the past) might help? https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/26217/16373